# How can I pass a component to ng-content in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular2-ngcontent

I am trying to find a simple way of nesting a component in another component, by referencing it inside the content area of the parent component. This would be the parent:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-foo',
    template: `
    <div>
        <p>Some content around the nested component</p>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
        <p>And some more content below the nested component</p>
    </div>
  `
})
export class Foo {
}
```

And then I want to use it like this:

```
<app-foo>
    <app-bar></app-bar>
</app-foo>
```

I think only strings are accepted inside the content area of a custom component, so this does not work. But it seems like a very generic use case and I can't find examples that do exactly this without making it very complicated. I am not an advanced Angular user so I like to keep things simple. Is there any documentation that I have missed, or are there any suggestions how to go about this?

Comment: This should just work.. ? Unless I’m missing something obvious..?

Comment: @MikeOne Oh really?? It's certainly intuitive enough, but it has never worked for me, so maybe I have a different problem...

Comment: Must be... because I use this pattern all the time..?